# powershell.exe -version 2.0 is Freezing ISE & Console (Version 4)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to emulate powershell version 2.0 in version 4.0

The following just freezes the application:

```
PS H:\> powershell.exe -version 2.0
```

I do get the following text but and the console continues to run and I am unable to execute further script.

```
Windows PowerShell 
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: that also happens with Version 3 in ISE (so trying to go down a version from ISE). I think this may be a bug or the downversion "feature" isn't supported in ISE 3 and 4. As an alternative, you can always use the PS console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the command window in ISE is not a real console window.  It's just pretending that it is.  In reality, it's running the commands in the background and copying the output to the command window.

Note that when you try to run `cmd.exe`, you get this:

```
Cannot start "cmd". Interactive console applications are not supported. 
To run the application, use the Start-Process cmdlet or use "Start PowerShell.exe" from the File menu.
To view/modify the list of blocked console applications, use $psUnsupportedConsoleApplications, or consult online help.
At line:0 char:0
```

Similarly, running `powershell.exe` alone gives me this:

```
Cannot start "powershell". Interactive console applications are not supported. 
To run the application, use the Start-Process cmdlet or use "Start PowerShell.exe" from the File menu.
To view/modify the list of blocked console applications, use $psUnsupportedConsoleApplications, or consult online help.
At line:0 char:0
```

I'm not sure why `powershell -version 2.0` works.  The ISE must think you're calling it non-interactively.

Note that it's not freezing.  It's waiting for the process to end.  You can end it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Using `Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-Version 2.0"` opens a new console window.

Comment: Fantastic - I just found a button four to the left of run script which opens powershell.exe too. Thanks for the great explanation and snippets.